# How to show google maps and street view in the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-street-view

I want to show google maps and street view and have a relation between them so that if the user moved in the map the street view will refresh, something like this http://www.mashedworld.com/DualMaps.aspx but without the birds eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of streetview

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple.html